# Which country's laws apply on Canusa Street / rue Canusa?

Tags: usa, canada, international-travel, borders

As a foreigner (and whether you are here is potentially debateable) and something happens to you on Canusa Street, what laws would you be under? Information online claims that the street falls into both countries (well, divided down the middle) but surely there must be some jurisdiction under which you fall?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canusa_Street

This is relevant to travel in cases of:

- insurance claims if you were only covered for insurance
- Canadian/US citizens for healthcare coverage
- law enforcement
- taxes applicable
- currency to use

and presumably more.

Comment: As much as the source is Wikipedia... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beebe_Plain

"Canusa Street (Quebec Route 247), the border between the two countries, runs through the middle of the village. Homes on the south side of Canusa Street are in the United States; their residents must obtain passports and report to Customs to leave their driveways."

This suggests to me that the street is entirely within Canada. The source for that doesn't appear to be online anymore though.

Comment: Is there any reason why you expect special rules for Canusa Street? International borders through populated areas are not *that* uncommon, the exact path of the border is probably well known and undisputed and it should be fairly easy to determine if any incident in border proximity happened in US or Canada.

Comment: Side question: Did you watch the Tom Scott video on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all borders which happen to be in a place where people are, if there is a legal question, specialist will look at where the person was when the incident happened.

If you have a health insurance which is only valid in the US, get a travel insurance that covers medical care (mostly emergencies only) when in Canada, so that if a series of accidents places you on Canadian ground before the final accident, you are covered.

In case of accidents where the exact location of the persons or their belongings are important, you should take a full set of photos all around, making sure you include visible border markings where important.

In daily life, the border will make little difference, because the people living in the area are aware of it and are ready with insurances and such.

It are the tourists who come to these border crossing areas, like to do shopping across the border, who might be confused and might even get in trouble.

As long as the border stays friendly, there will be few problems.

Berlin, after it was divided after the war and more so when the wall was build, is an example that a place does not need to be on a national border for difficult situation to come in existence. (In that case, a 'no man's land' was created between the people living near.)